# Is it possible to write a php script that accepts emails (like an email bot)

Tags: php, email, bots

I would like to write a script that can receive e-mail and then do something depending on instructions in that e-mail, but I have no idea where to start with this.  Is this possible with PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an old (but good) email on evolt about piping incoming emails to a php script.

http://www.evolt.org/incoming_mail_and_php

If you don't have terminal access, you could instead use the imap/pop functions in php to read a mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

No. Only a mail server can read email. However, you can have the mail server pipe the output to a PHP CLI script.

Comment: PHP can be setup to act as a mail server.

Comment: The -1 wasn't me, but I think you are taking the question a little too literally. You're not a mail server, but you get email too.

Comment: True - but then any (and I mean just about any) language could be used for a mail server. And I don't think that's what @DKinzer wanted.